# Why is my DLOOKUP returning only a partially correct record?

Tags: ms-access, vba, filtered-lookup

Alright. This is my first post ever so I'll try to be as detailed as I can.  I have a Person_AfterUpdate() event on a Form named frm_Contact_Info, that is supposed to check a table, named "tbl_Contact_Info," for an existing record.  If the record exists, then a message pops up stating that the record already exists, and to check the name.  Then it asks if I am creating a new record with the existing name, or if the record that is returned is the same person. The problem I am having is that the DLookup shows the correct name, but does not return the correct phone number or address to my form.

Here is my code.  I'm not super skilled at programming, but I tried to make it as understandable as possible.  If you want screen shots, let me know. This is the first time I've actually tried to build a database, and I know my skills are not as great as some of yours.  I've tried to research as much as I could to find the answer to this, but everything I've tried so far brings me back to this problem where the DLOOKUP is returning the correct NewPerson, but not the correct phone number or e-mail address.  Please help!

```
Private Sub Person_AfterUpdate()

Dim NewPerson As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim PersID As Integer

On Error GoTo E:

NewPerson = Me.Person.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[Person] = " & "'" & NewPerson & "'"

If Me.Person = DLookup("[Person]", "tbl_Contact_Info", stLinkCriteria) Then
    MsgBox "The name, " & NewPerson & ", has already been added to the database." _
    & vbCr & vbCr & "Please check the name and try again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate Information"
    Me.Undo
End If

PersID = DLookup("[ID]", "tbl_Contact_Info", stLinkCriteria)
Me.DataEntry = False
DoCmd.FindRecord PersID, , , , , acCurrent

Response = MsgBox("Are you adding a new record with the same name?", vbYesNo, "New or Existing Record")

If Response = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec, 1
    Me!Person.Value = NewPerson
Else
    Me.DataEntry = True
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec, 1

End If
Exit Sub

E:
Me!Person.Value = NewPerson
End Sub`
```

Comment: I assume you are using the same criteria (`stLinkCriteria`), and have you tried to do a normal query? `select * from tbl_Contact_Info where Person='aperson';` to see if you have the same person more times in your table, and if the data is correct.

Comment: I have not tried the normal query, but I can tell you that there is more than one entry of the same person.  The idea is to have a contact list, where I can have multiples of the same name.  Forgive my ignorance in this matter, since I am still new to this type of coding, but where do I enter in this query?

Comment: See for example:
 [Where to type SQL statements in Microsoft Access](http://www.jaffainc.com/SQLStatementsInAccess.htm#Access2007); or
[Introduction to Access SQL](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Introduction-to-Access-SQL-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e)

Comment: @agold I did as instructed, but the query did not return any results, even though I made sure to have multiples of one name in the table. I tried to comment out the "IF, Then, Else" statements from "Response = " down to "Exit Sub." When I run the code that way, the form populates the correct name, but not the correct Phone Number or E-Mail address from the record. It appears to be ready to append the record instead of being able to add a new one.

Comment: Can you also show the part where you retrieve the phone number and e-mail in your question? And the query/queries you tried.

Comment: I thought that because I have the [ID] column referenced, it should be pulling the e-mail address and phone number based on that record. Is it possible that there is something wrong with  the statements after my message box?

Comment: I don't see where you pull that information (e-mail/phone). And after `DoCmd.FindRecord` (selects the record you want), the first thing you do is `DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec, 1` which creates a new record, which will then be the current record.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Here's an update, without really changing anything.  First, I finally got the SQL query to pull the information that I need it to.  Now I just need to figure out how to integrate that into my code.  Second, the issue is with three lines of code.   PersID = DLookup("[ID]", "tbl_Contact_Info", stLinkCriteria)
Me.DataEntry = False
DoCmd.FindRecord PersID, , , , ,acCurrent                                                     It's after these lines that the correct record should be pulled into the form.  But it defaults to the first record of the table

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have multiple records with the same value in the attribute you are using as your lookup value?

Comment: I do have more than one entry of the same person.  This is supposed to be the idea, as I'm attempting to build a contact list.